# Is there a way to do a search in Sitecore against with Lucene using a dynamic field?

Tags: content-search, lucene

My client needs me to write a speak app that can do a search where they can type in whatever field they want to equal a value in the search bar. Is there a way to do a search against Lucene to within Sitecore to allow a dynamic field?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but do you just want to pass in the field as a name and the value to search? Or is this deeper and you want the full speak pipelines for doing this search?

```
var yourField = "content";
var yourValue = "hello";

using (var searchContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
    var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(x => x[yourField] == yourValue);

    if (result != null)
    {
        var results = query.GetResults();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh no, this should suffice provided this works